# How can I check a remote's HEAD of a different branch from a shallow clone?

Tags: git

I recently changed the way my servers clone to be shallow, to speed up deployment:

```
git clone -b $BRANCH --depth 1 git@github.com:initech/rounding.git .
```

The problem is, the update mechanism does the following:

```
LOCAL=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
REMOTE=$(git rev-parse origin/$NEWBRANCH)

if [ $LOCAL = $REMOTE ]; then
    echo "Up-to-date"
else
    blah...
fi
```

Previously this was fine, however now I get `fatal: Needed a single revision`, because git does not know about the existence of any other branches.

How can I pull in information about the branch I want to switch to, and check its HEAD commit on origin *without* checking it out (since I want to leave this checkout as is - as it's running the server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly: the information is simply not there.

If you can consult another, more-complete Git repository, you can find the answer there.  The precise mechanism for this will (obviously) depend on just how you go about reaching with and talking to this other, more-complete Git repository—but there is a built-in mechanism: `git ls-remote`.

Run `git ls-remote` manually, in one of your own repositories, to see it in action.  Note that it calls up the remote (usually `origin` but [you can choose which remote; see the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html)) via some Git transport, which means whoever runs it must be permitted to access the other repository.

Note also that it gets these reference names *as seen on the remote*.  *Your* Git stores *your* copy of "what the other Git calls `refs/heads/master` (branch `master`)" under *your* `refs/remotes/origin/master`. This keeps it separate from *your* `refs/heads/master`.  Their Git, of course, doesn't have to keep their `master` separate from their `master` ... so *their* Git stores this under the full name `refs/heads/master`.  This means your test will have to change accordingly.